# VC++ cannot find the exe when compiling

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, exe

I have a problem while trying to run/debug my C++ Desktop Application in VS.

I get a error message telling me that the DieGame.exe (in the debug folder) cannot be found!

I also get numerous errors (c2065) in the console telling me i have undeclared identifiers all over in DieGame.cpp file?

Any ideas?

DieGame.cpp file:

```
#include "Die.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Die die8 = createDie(8);
    cout << "Rolling a D8: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << read(die8) << " ";
        roll(die8);
}
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Die.cpp File:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Die.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int roll() {
    return rand() % 6 + 1;
}
static int randomValue(int max) {
    return rand() % max + 1;
}
Die createDie(int max) {
    Die die;
    die.max = max;
    die.value = randomValue(max);
    return die;
}
void roll(Die die) {
    die.value = randomValue(die.max);
}

int read(Die die) {
    return die.value;
}
```

Die.h Header:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_DIE
#define INCLUDED_DIE

using namespace std;

int roll();
#endif 

struct Die
{
    int value;
    int max;
};

Die createDie(int max);
void roll(Die die);
int read(Die die);
```

Comment: `#include "pch.h"` should be the first file. Your program is failing to compile (or link) so the *.exe file is never created. Show the exact compile/link errors.

Answer (score 0):

In Die.h Header, move the `#endif` line to the end of the file.